# :read after cursor instead of after line

Tags: external-command

I use `:r !uuidgen` frequently to insert a new uuid into the buffer. This works, but I am generally attempting to insert the uuid between quotes, and `:r !uuidgen` prints the uuid on a new line.

To get around this issue, I am currently using a simple keymap:

```
nnoremap <C-u> mm:r!uuidgen<CR>dW"_dd`mp
```

This macro sets the mark `mm`, inserts the uuid `r!uuidgen`, deletes the inserted uuid `dW`, deletes the extra line `"_dd`, goes back to the mark `BACKTICKm`, and finally paste the uuid `p`.

Is there a way to `:r` right after the cursor without this macro/keybinding that wastes a register?

Comment: [SU question](http://superuser.com/a/457974/334516), also with workarounds like this one.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the expression register `"=` and `system()`:

```
<C-r>=system("uuidgen | tr -d '\n'")<CR>
```

It would look like that in an insert mode mapping:

```
inoremap <key> <C-r>=system("uuidgen | tr -d '\n'")<CR>
```

or, with an expression mapping:

```
inoremap <expr> <key> system("uuidgen \| tr -d '\n'")
```

Answer (score 5):

From insert mode, you can hit <kbd>Ctrl-R</kbd>, and then type:

```
=system('uuidgen')
```

Note that this will add a trailing newline, because that's what `uuidgen` outputs; to fix this, we could use:

```
=system('uuidgen')[:-2]
```

To remove the newline.

From [`:help i_CTRL-R`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/insert.txt.html#i_CTRL-R):

> Insert the contents of a register.  Between typing CTRL-R and the second
>   character, '"' will be displayed to indicate that you are expected to enter
>   the name of a register.
>
> [..]
>
> '='     the expression register: you are prompted to enter an expression (see
>   expression)

To bind this to <kbd>Ctrl-u</kbd> like your example, you can use:

```
nnoremap <C-u> i<C-r>=system('uuidgen')[:-2]<CR><Esc>
```

Answer (score 2):

One more, with `:python`:

```
:py import uuid, vim; vim.command(':normal i' + str(uuid.uuid1()))
```

You could map as:

```
:inoremap <key> <esc>:py import uuid, vim; vim.command(':normal a' + str(uuid.uuid1()))<cr>a
```

The UUIDs are generated by the [Python UUID module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/uuid.html).

Comment: This is a rather twisted way to go about, though.

Answer (score 1):

This is perhaps less preferable than using a pure-vim solution, however, if you use a snippet manager such as [Ultisnips](https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips) then you could try [adding a snippet](https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips/blob/master/doc/UltiSnips.txt#L568) such as the following:

```
snippet uuid "insert new uuid" w
`uuidgen`
endsnippet
```

This way you can type `uuid` and hit your expand trigger in insert-mode and `uuid` will be replaced with the output of the relevant shell command.  This, of course, can be easily adapted for other commands and expanded upon in powerful ways as outlined in the Ultisnips docs.